# Problems installing virtualenvwrapper in Cygwin

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to get started with a book called "TDD with Python", OS W10.  As part of the setup it wants you to install virtualenvwrapper. The recommendation is to use GitBash in Windows... but I've been using Cygwin for quite a bit and didn't like GitBash when I looked at it some time ago.

Python version is 3.6.  I installed virtualenvwrapper by going

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

This seemed to work OK.

Trying to add the relevant setup line to my .bashrc did not go so well:

```
echo "source virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

output:

> /usr/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
>   virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization
>   hooks.
>
> If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
>   check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is set
>   properly.

At least this proves that virtualenvwrapper.sh is being run...

In fact there is no such directory as `/usr/bin` ... so I added a preceding line in .bashrc pointing to what I hoped might be what it might be wanting to see for this VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON environment variable (do we call them that in Linux?).

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/cygdrive/d/apps/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper
```

Now I get

> bash:
>   /cygdrive/d/apps/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper:
>   Is a directory virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the
>   initialization hooks.
>
> If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
>   check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
>   VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/cygdrive/d/apps/Python/Python36/Lib/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper
>   and that PATH is set properly.

*Main question: what is VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON meant to point at?* An executable file? Any clues to help me recognise the desired target would be much appreciated!

**POST-ANSWER ENLIGHTENMENT** Just in case anyone stumbles this way, just to let you know: after phd gave me the answer to this I found other problems.

Eventually I managed to install virtualenvwrapper by doing this:

```
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper
```

... use the latest Cygwin setup .exe to install **pip3**.  Note the **3**!

then go

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
echo "source virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

... success! but quickly followed by another puzzle: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760854/why-does-my-cygwin-setup-tell-me-python3-6-not-installed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` should point to python binary: `/usr/bin/python`, e.g.

Comment: Thanks... as I say, (strangely perhaps) there is no /usr/bin directory in this cygwin setup.  I've now changed the env var to point to /bin/python3 ... and now (not surprisingly) I'm getting another error: "Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' ... no module named 'virtualenvwrapper'"... But thanks, you get the points!

Comment: Are you sure you have exactly one python? It seems `pip` installed `virtualenvwrapper` to a different python. Try to (re)install it with your choosen python: `/bin/python3 -m pip install virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: Thanks... I've done some searching since you helped me clear this hurdle: uninstalled virtualenvwrapper, added the pip3 module using the Cygwin setup .exe, tried again... it worked! ... but (surprise!) now I have **another** mystifying thing about non-recognition of Python3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760854/why-does-my-cygwin-setup-tell-me-python3-6-not-installed

Comment: The directory `/bin` is mounted at `/usr/bin`. You can see that by using the `mount` command. It shows how windows directories are mapped into the posix style directory structure used by cygwin.