# Why does my Cygwin setup tell me Python3.6 not installed?

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin, virtualenvwrapper, pip

Python 3.6 has been installed (using the Cygwin setup .exe file, update, etc.). The executable is located in `/bin/` ... or is it located in `/usr/bin/`? Cygwin `ls` command shows that `/usr/bin` exists... but on Windows this directory is non-existent.  Also the contents of both directories are identical, including if I change a filename... but I haven't as yet found a symlink (in `/usr` or in `/` ) to explain this!

I'm struggling to get virtualenvwrapper installed (this is part of a preparation required to follow along with a book, TDD With Python).

I just overcame a first hurdle (eventually) by realising I had to install virtualenvwrapper using pip3, not pip! ... I feel like I'm in at the deep end.

So I did:

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
echo "source virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

... then I did

```
mkvirtualenv --python3=`py -3.6 -c"import sys; print(sys.executable)"` superlists
```

(NB "python3" is the correct name of the symlink which points to the Python3 executable in `/bin/`; there is a "python" symlink but that points to Python2.7)

And I got:

> Requested Python version (3.6) not installed
> Using base prefix '/usr'
>   
> New python executable in
>   /home/Chris/.virtualenvs/superlists/bin/python3
> Also creating
>   executable in /home/Chris/.virtualenvs/superlists/bin/python
>   
> Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
>   
> virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
>   /home/Chris/.virtualenvs/superlists/bin/predeactivate
>   
> virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
>   /home/Chris/.virtualenvs/superlists/bin/postdeactivate
>   
> virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
>   /home/Chris/.virtualenvs/superlists/bin/preactivate
>   
> virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
>   /home/Chris/.virtualenvs/superlists/bin/postactivate
>   
> virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating
>   /home/Chris/.virtualenvs/superlists/bin/get_env_details 
> (superlists)

Anyone know what's going on? How do I get the system to recognise that Python3.6 is actually installed?

**Later** Or... am I being very dense? Maybe making a virtual environment using this module always involves installing a new Python executable?

**Later still** I'm still not clear about this... but it isn't stopping me from using `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` and generally getting on with the book. Despite complaining Python doesn't exist the setup appears (as far as I can tell!) to be using the symlinks under the directories in directory .virtualenv/ to one of the Python symlinks in /bin/ ...

Comment: Does Cygwin have `py` command? I think it's Windows-only.

Comment: It might be easier to get going on windows by using `virtualenvwrapper-win` and the regular python-on-windows toolchain, or install windows subsystem for linux + Ubuntu (although I've barely touched the latter).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In fact I'm managing to get on with the thing despite this discouraging message!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About first question

> /usr/bin and /usr/lib are by default also automatic mount points
>   generated by the Cygwin DLL similar to the way the root directory is
>   evaluated. /usr/bin points to the directory the Cygwin DLL is
>   installed in, /usr/lib is supposed to point to the /lib directory.

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

For the second, to check if phyton3 is installed

```
$ cygcheck -c python3
```

and as mentioned by `phd` the py command is not a cygwin one, so probably you are mixing something.